# How `print()` works？

Tags: python, python-3.x

A python3.x code demo：

```py
def fun():
    global x
    y.append(6)
    x = 6

x = 3
y = [3]
print(x, y, fun(), x, y)
```

The segment outputs:

```
3 [3, 6] None 6 [3, 6]
```

If the process of `print()` calculates all of the items and then outputs the items, then that explains why the result of `y` before `fun()` and after `fun()` are both `[3, 6]`, as they are here. But why then are the values of `x` before and after the function `fun()` different?

Comment: Because you asked for that to happen by declaring it `global`.

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate of this question nor does it answer it - the linked question is talking about the use of global variables; this question is talking about how `print()` calculates its values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link explains the variable assignment very well. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html:

> Fact: Python passes function arguments by assigning to them.
> For example :

```py
def fn(a):
    pass
    
x = 10
```

When we say `fn(x)`, it's going to be `a = x`. Another rule is the arguments are evaluated from left to right.

After saying those two rules, let me re-write the print function in a specific way that matches to our example:

```py
def print_(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, sep=' ', end='\n'):
    sys.stdout.write(str(var1) + sep)
    sys.stdout.write(str(var2) + sep)
    sys.stdout.write(str(var3) + sep)
    sys.stdout.write(str(var4) + sep)
    sys.stdout.write(str(var5) + sep)
    sys.stdout.write(end)

print_(x, y, fun(), x, y)
```

Python holds the value of the global `x` inside the local variable `var1`.

```py
var1 = x    # `x` is 3 now
```

After the `fun()` function executes, the `x` in global changes to `6`, but the point is `var1` is still 3 not 6:

```py
var1 = x = 3
x = 6
print(var1)  # 3
```

...and `print_` is going to use it's local variables (`var1` not `x`).

But from now on whenever Python sees the `x`, it stores `6` instead. so `var4` is 6.

```py
var4 = x    # `x` is 6 now
```

But since the `y` is a list and you **mutated** the list, both `var2` and `y` are seeing the change ! Because they both point to the same object:

```py
var2 = y = [3]
y.append(6)
print(var2)   # [3, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call a function, like `print` in your example, the arguments are evaluated from left to right.

Your call has `x` as an argument twice. The first one gets evaluated with the original value, `3`. Then `fun()` gets called, which has the side effect of changing the global variable `x`. When you evaluate `x` again afterwards, you get the updated value, `6`.

It might be a bit clearer if you used functions calls for all the arguments, as that would let you print some output too:

```
def get_x():
    print("x is", x)
    return x

def change_x():
    global x
    x += 1
    print("x changed")

x = 0

print("args evaluated left to right:", get_x(), change_x(), get_x())
```

The output from that is:

```
x is 0
x changed
x is 1
args evaluated left to right: 0 None 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `print` copies arguments in local variables, but each arguments are different local variables and are evaluated left to right. What happens giving your line `print( x, y, func(), x, y)` is this :

**1.** x is evaluated and copied in local variable. `xLocal1 = x = 3`

**2.** y is evaluated and copied in local variable. `yLocal1 = [3]`

**3.** func() is evaluated, it changes `x` **AND BOTH** `yLocal1` and `y` as there iss a `global x` that specifies it applies to only global variable and not local. `x = 6, yLocal1 = [3,6], y = [3,6]`. It changes the variable from last step

**4.** x is evaluated and copied in xLocal2. `xLocal2 = x = 6`

**5.** y is evaluated and copied in yLocal2. `yLocal2 = y = [3,6]`

**6.** And it finally prints all the local variables `xLocal1, yLocal1, xLocal2 and yLocal2` that equals to `3, [3,6], 6, [3,6]`